# How to end a loop, from outside the loop in python

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I am making a pygame game with python 3.8.3,
In my game I have a starting screen, that is inside this while loop:

```py
def game_intro(): 
    intro = True 
    mixer.music.load("musicIntro.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(0.02) 
    mixer.music.play(-1) 
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    intro = False
        screen.blit(startscherm_img, bordrect) 
        clock.tick(30)
        button("Start",302,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"start")
        button("Music",553,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"toggleMusic")
        button("Quit",803,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"quit")
        pygame.display.flip() 
game_intro()
```

I am calling for my button function that I have defined above:

```py
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None): 
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() 
    if x+w > mousePos[0] > x and y+h > mousePos[1] > y: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x,y,w,h)) 
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None: 
            if action == "toggleMusic": 
                PAUSE.toggle()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            elif action == "quit": 
                pygame.quit()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            elif action == "start": 
                time.sleep(0.3)
                intro = False
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x,y,w,h)) 

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("Bauhaus 93",30)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objecten(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

It basically just checks for mouse clicking within a certain area, and if it detects that it executes code.

Now on my starting screen I have a button start, I would like it to end the game_intro() loop, however trying `intro = False` does not result in anything. 
trying `break` does not work, as it would have to be in the loop itself.

So my question is: How do I make this start button actually end the game_intro() loop ?

P.S I am quite new to Python

Comment: If you make it into a class, then you could define intro as a field and read/update it in the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are setting `intro = False` inside the function `button`, but you also have a variable named `intro` inside the `game_intro` function. Eventhough they have the same name, Python treats them as distinct variables.

In order to make effective the change on the `intro` variable from one function to the other, you need to either set the `intro` variable as global, or to pass the `intro` variable as a parameter between the two functions.

Option 1:

```
intro = True

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None): 
    global intro
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() 
    if x+w > mousePos[0] > x and y+h > mousePos[1] > y: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x,y,w,h)) 
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None: 
            if action == "toggleMusic": 
                PAUSE.toggle()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            elif action == "quit": 
                pygame.quit()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            elif action == "start": 
                time.sleep(0.3)
                intro = False

def game_intro(): 
    global intro
    mixer.music.load("musicIntro.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(0.02) 
    mixer.music.play(-1) 
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    intro = False
        screen.blit(startscherm_img, bordrect) 
        clock.tick(30)
        button("Start",302,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"start")
        button("Music",553,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"toggleMusic")
        button("Quit",803,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"quit")
        pygame.display.flip() 
game_intro()
```

Option 2:

```
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, intro, action=None): 
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() 
    if x+w > mousePos[0] > x and y+h > mousePos[1] > y: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x,y,w,h)) 
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None: 
            if action == "toggleMusic": 
                PAUSE.toggle()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            elif action == "quit": 
                pygame.quit()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            elif action == "start": 
                time.sleep(0.3)
                intro = False
    return intro

def game_intro(): 
    intro = True
    mixer.music.load("musicIntro.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(0.02) 
    mixer.music.play(-1) 
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    intro = False
        screen.blit(startscherm_img, bordrect) 
        clock.tick(30)
        intro = button("Start",302,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,intro,"start")
        intro = button("Music",553,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,intro,"toggleMusic")
        intro = button("Quit",803,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,intro,"quit")
            pygame.display.flip() 
game_intro()
```

Comment: I tried both your solutions, but both of them come with an error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'intro' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You're right, the `intro` definition was missing in option 2. Please try again with option 2, I edited it and now should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some OOP. Try creating it inside a class like this:

```
class Intro:

  def __init__(self):
    self.intro = True

  def game_intro(self): 
    mixer.music.load("musicIntro.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(0.02) 
    mixer.music.play(-1) 
    while self.intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.intro = False
        screen.blit(startscherm_img, bordrect) 
        clock.tick(30)
        button("Start",302,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"start")
        button("Music",553,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"toggleMusic")
        button("Quit",803,517,94,44,donkerOranje,lichtOranje,"quit")
        pygame.display.flip() 

  def button(self, msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None): 
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() 
    if x+w > mousePos[0] > x and y+h > mousePos[1] > y: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x,y,w,h)) 
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None: 
            if action == "toggleMusic": 
                PAUSE.toggle()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            elif action == "quit": 
                pygame.quit()
                time.sleep(0.3)
            elif action == "start": 
                time.sleep(0.3)
                self.intro = False


obj = Intro()
start = obj.gameintro()
```

The `intro` is defined inside an instance using `self` so it can be called anywhere inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

All though I have not done python in a while you could try running your loop as a new thread then kill it once finish as a thread manually in all honesty setting intro to false should have worked I would do some debugging first to actually check if intro is being set to false. Although upon reading your code further I noticed that you actually call the function game_intro() twice which would cause you to loop as the variable intro  is defined in side of the function so calling the function game_intro() would reset the loop so maybe remove the calling at the end since you already have it in a while loop. Another option is to define the variable intro out side of the function cheers

Answer (score 0):

Threading Events

Assign a global scope variable (outside the two functions) as a `threading.Event` instance.

Then, set and clear that event when you want to control the loop.

```
import threading


do_intro_loop = threading.Event


def button(action=None):
  if action == "start":
    do_intro_loop.clear()

def into():
  do_intro_loop.set()
  while do_intro_loop.is_set():
    # show do intro stuff here
    pass

intro()
```